# delete Table View Cells from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a table View full of appended messages with the logged in user and other users of the app. When I swipe a cell, I want to be able to delete it from Firebase and also automatically from the tableView. I managed to get the cell deleted from Firebase but not from the tableView. This is how the messages are initially loaded into the tableView:

```
  func loadData()
    {
        guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                for post in postsDictionary {
                    let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    for (id, value) in messages {
                        let info = value as! [String: AnyObject]


                        let convoId = info["convoId"]
                        let toId = info["ReceiverId"] as! String!
                        let fromId = info["senderId"] as! String!


                        if (toId == self.loggedInUserUid  || fromId == self.loggedInUserUid) {

        let refs = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(convoId as! String).child(uid)
        refs.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in


            self.messageId = snapshot.key



        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").child(convoId as! String).child(self.messageId!)

                            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)


                if let receiver = message.convoId {
                    self.messagesDictionary[receiver] = message

                    self.messages = Array(self.messagesDictionary.values)
                    print(self.messages)
                    self.messages.sort(by: { (message1, message2) -> Bool in


                        return (message1.timestamp?.int32Value)! > (message2.timestamp?.int32Value)!

                    })
                }

                //this will crash because of background thread, so lets call this on dispatch_async main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.MessageTableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

        }, withCancel: nil) })}
                    }

                }}})

    }
```

Here is how I perform the delete function in Firebase and attempt to perform a delete function in the tableView:

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

        guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }

        let message = messages[(indexPath.row)]


       self.deletemessage = message.convoId


        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {

                for post in postsDictionary {
                    let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
                    for (id, value) in messages {
                        let info = value as! [String: AnyObject]


                        let convoId = info["convoId"]

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(self.deletemessage!).child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            self.messageId = snapshot.key

            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(self.deletemessage!).child(uid).child( self.messageId!).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error \(error)")
                }else{



                }})})}}}})

            self.messages.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.MessageTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

        }
    }
```

it deletes from the tableView but crashes and gives me an error on `self.messages.remove(at: indexPath.row)` fatal error: Index out of Range.

Comment: Do you want to delete a logged user from Authenticated users or just some part of your data in database like child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {

            let state = id[indexPath.row] //it store the child key to be removed. here id array is not displayed but used as backend process

            print(state) // (Not required)

            names.remove(at: indexPath.row) //Remove the selected name from array used in TableView that is displayed in cell

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade) // TableView Animation 

            Database.database().reference().child("artists").child(id[indexPath.row]).removeValue() // remove the child referred using id from database

            id.remove(at: indexPath.row) // removing selected if from id array locally 

        }
    }
```

Try the following code In your case please and let me know issue still Exists

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if editingStyle == .delete {

guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
    return
}
let message = messages[(indexPath.row)]

self.deletemessage = message.convoId

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("messages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
    if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        for post in postsDictionary {
            let messages = post.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            for (id, value) in messages {
                let info = value as! [String: AnyObject]
                let convoId = info["convoId"]
                let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(self.deletemessage!).child(uid)
                ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                    self.messageId = snapshot.key

                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user-messages").child(self.deletemessage!).child(uid).child( self.messageId!).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("error \(error)")
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        }}})
    self.messages.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.MessageTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
}
```

Try this it occur because you are deleting value correct but under a handler which even caused a error in my project . data in messages is loaded from database so if value is not delete from database it will update again even if u remove from array. so please try this code

Comment: I feel like I did the same thing. it deletes but then I get the error fatal error: Index out of Range.

Comment: I tried your code style in my code , is this happening same that value is deleted from firebase but when it comes to deleting value from tableview it crash and when you reload app the name u tried to delete was delete d?

Comment: it works and it doesn't crash. However, When I type in new messages to the users the messages automatically delete without me swiping to delete

Comment: The only time the messages don't delete when I type is when I restart the app

Comment: Was the previous problem resolved ? and when you deleted a message using swipe and after in the same launch when you type a new message it delete Automatically without swiping even from database ?

Comment: Yes so when I type out a message and then delete it by swiping, it deletes like I want it to. but if I  type out a new message in the same launch it automatically deletes. if I relaunch the app, it does not automatically delete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149186/discussion-between-ios-geek-and-juelizabeth).

Comment: let's please continue in chat

Comment: remove override before your function of tableview